# Not able to get Jsonstring from this link

Tags: java

```
        String fileURL="https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=192.168.6.9";

    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);
```

Full code:
 try {

```
String url = "http://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=192.168.6.9";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);  
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);

boolean redirect = false;

// normally, 3xx is redirect
int status = conn.getResponseCode();
if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
    redirect = true;
}

System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);

if (redirect) {

    // get redirect url from "location" header field
    String newUrl =conn.getHeaderField("Location");
   newUrl=newUrl.replace("https://", "http://");
    // get the cookie if need, for login
    String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

    // open the new connnection again
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

    System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);

}

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    html.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + html.toString());
System.out.println("Done");

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
OUTPUT:
Request URL ... http://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=192.168.6.9
Response Code ... 301
Redirect to URL : http://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=192.168.6.9
URL Content... 
301 Moved Permanently

## 301 Moved Permanently

---

nginx
Done

Iam not able to get json from this link, It gives 301 response code, I tried to get the redirected URL from HTTP header part, eventhough, It returns same URL and same 301 response code, please give java code solution to get JSON string from this URL.

Comment: A [301 HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) code means that this address was permanently moved. It also returns the location of the new address. You have to check it to make another request or change your code with the new address

Comment: Note that you Issue an HTTP request to an HTTPS address, so you get redirected to the HTTPS address of same resource

Comment: Could you add the complete response of the URL ?

Comment: @Yossi Vainshtein

Comment: @Yossi Vainshtein:{"status":"success","description":"Data successfully received.","data":{"geo":{"host":"192.168.6.9","ip":"192.168.6.9","route":null,"rdns":"192.168.6.9","asn":"","isp":"","abuse":null,"country_name":null,"country_code":null,"region":null,"city":null,"postal_code":null,"continent_code":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"dma_code":null,"area_code":null,"timezone":false,"datetime":"na"}}}

Comment: If I change to HTTPS It shows TimeOut error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
String fileURL="https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=192.168.6.9";
URL url;
    try
    {
        final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
        url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //add request header
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Go through this link https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: OP's request is send, but a 301 is received, is this going to correct the problem ? Funny thing is that you force the User-Agent to Mozilla/5.0, I don't understand why... **You might want to explain you solution**

Comment: @AxelH For me above given code throws java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server. So I have added "User-Agent". It works fine. Hope this will solve his problem.

Comment: For me, It returns java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect Excption

Comment: @Raghaven For me it is working. Getting response code as 200. Hope there is an issue in your network. Can you access that link through your browser ?

Comment: @Prasath: http://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=192.168.6.9. Did u used this link to get json..?

Comment: Yes I used this fileURL="https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=192.168.6.9"
Can you access that link through your browser ?

Comment: @Prasath: Yes I can able to acces it in browser, but not able to fetch the data via java code.

Comment: Now I am getting same after tried your full code. Wait for some time to work out.

Comment: @Raghaven would you have an internal proxy configured in your browser that wouldn't be configured for your Java environment? More specifically it could be configured for http (which would explain why you correctly receive a 301) but not for https

Comment: @prasath:Thank you,It is a VPN issue in system